# how to make the lower UIView be pinned to the upper UIView in the UIScrollView if other UIView with the hidden option?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

How to make the lower UIView be pinned to the upper UIView in the UIScrollView if other UIView with the hidden option?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag the hidden one height constraint as IBOutlet and change it's constant like that

```
 self.hiddenViewHCon.constant = 0
 self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and the lower view will be pinned to the top , also don't forget to set this

```
 self.hiddenView.clipsToBounds = true
```

Comment: sorry, but I do not know how. I'm still new to development. And i try

Comment: you use auto layout ??

Comment: if you put a fixed height for that view you want to hide select that constraint as you make a label or a button do same with it to make it available at run time so you can change it

Comment: error "value of type ViewController has no member "hiddenViewCon""